# How to put html <canvas> in a Mediawiki page

Tags: javascript, html, templates, canvas, mediawiki

My question is about inserting `<canvas></canvas>` into a mediawiki page.

(Edit: This codes works, but it takes about 5 minutes for it to register, see below for full answer)

I was able to put a javascript "Hello World" out put onto my mediawiki site.

To do so I have the following:

1. In my MediaWiki:Common.js page I have:

```
(function () {

  var myElement = document.getElementById('mw-hello-world');
  myElement.innerHTML = '<html>Hello World!!!</html>';

}());
```

2. In my Template:Helloworld page I have:

```
<div id="mw-hello-world"></div>
```

3. In my main page I have:

```
{{Helloworld}}
```

I now want to put a `<canvas></canvas>` on my main page. A guy at Mediawiki called [Bawolff](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Udkzwodfdm3ns2uk) said the following

```
"You would need to write an extension 
(Or put it entirely in a javascript file like the page MediaWiki:Common.js on your wiki)"
```

The problem is, `<canvas></canvas>` doesn't work by itself on any page. So I am wondering where to put `<canvas></canvas>`.
As you all can tell, I'm not a real programmer, so I was hoping for some ideas.
Thanks

Aslo, I did try doing the above, but with the code:

```
(function () {

  var myElement = document.getElementById('mw-Mycanvas');
  myElement.innerHTML = '<html><canvas width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas></html>';

}());
And then changing everything appropriately. But it just comes up as blank. But if I do this in HTML I get a red box.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.getElementById('your-id').appendChild(canvas);
```

Or:

```js
document.getElementById('your-id').innerHTML = '<canvas></canvas>';
```

References:

- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`Node#appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: the code: ``` document.getElementById('your-id').innerHTML = '<canvas></canvas>'; ``` worked perfectly, thanks, but it took about 5 minutes before it registered. The top code is a little hard because I don't know where the canvas goes yet, still figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
The code I wrote actually does work.
But I guess there was some kind of delay, of about 5 minutes. I don't know.
I will try InSync's suggestions also and post the results.
Thanks

I wrote the following:

1. In MediaWiki:Common.js:

```
(function () {

  var myElement = document.getElementById('mw-Mycanvas');
  myElement.innerHTML = '<html><canvas width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas></html>';

}());
```

2. In Template:Mycanvas I wrote:

```
<div id="mw-Mycanvas"></div>
```

3. Im Main Page I wrote:

```
{{Mycanvas}}
```